# KC-SERVICES0089: Failed to run scheduled task ClearExpiredClientInitialAccessTokens

Tags: sql-server, keycloak

I use Keycloak 10.0.2 and SQL Server as database. Sometimes I get an error in Keycloak which prevents the application to run properly and the only solution is to restart the application.

Seems that connection gets closed somehow and keycloak is not able to open it again. What could be the reason?

> 2020-06-22 09:09:28,649 ERROR [org.keycloak.services] (Timer-2)
> KC-SERVICES0089: Failed to run scheduled task
> ClearExpiredClientInitialAccessTokens:
> javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
> org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare
> statement
> at org.hibernate@5.3.15.Final//org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
> at org.hibernate@5.3.15.Final//org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
> at org.hibernate@5.3.15.Final//org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.executeUpdate(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1594)
> at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@10.0.2//org.keycloak.models.jpa.JpaRealmProvider.removeExpiredClientInitialAccess(JpaRealmProvider.java:826)
> at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-infinispan@10.0.2//org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.RealmCacheSession.removeExpiredClientInitialAccess(RealmCacheSession.java:1208)
> at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@10.0.2//org.keycloak.services.scheduled.ClearExpiredClientInitialAccessTokens.run(ClearExpiredClientInitialAccessTokens.java:30)
> at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@10.0.2//org.keycloak.services.scheduled.ClusterAwareScheduledTaskRunner$1.call(ClusterAwareScheduledTaskRunner.java:56)
> at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@10.0.2//org.keycloak.services.scheduled.ClusterAwareScheduledTaskRunner$1.call(ClusterAwareScheduledTaskRunner.java:52)
> at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-infinispan@10.0.2//org.keycloak.cluster.infinispan.InfinispanClusterProvider.executeIfNotExecuted(InfinispanClusterProvider.java:78)
> at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@10.0.2//org.keycloak.services.scheduled.ClusterAwareScheduledTaskRunner.runTask(ClusterAwareScheduledTaskRunner.java:52)
> at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@10.0.2//org.keycloak.services.scheduled.ScheduledTaskRunner.run(ScheduledTaskRunner.java:45)
> at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@10.0.2//org.keycloak.timer.basic.BasicTimerProvider$1.run(BasicTimerProvider.java:51)
> at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:556)
> at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:506) Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare
> statement
> at org.hibernate@5.3.15.Final//org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
> at org.hibernate@5.3.15.Final//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
> at org.hibernate@5.3.15.Final//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:186)
> at org.hibernate@5.3.15.Final//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:81)
> at org.hibernate@5.3.15.Final//org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.exec.BasicExecutor.doExecute(BasicExecutor.java:87)
> at org.hibernate@5.3.15.Final//org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.exec.BasicExecutor.execute(BasicExecutor.java:59)
> at org.hibernate@5.3.15.Final//org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.exec.DeleteExecutor.execute(DeleteExecutor.java:109)
> at org.hibernate@5.3.15.Final//org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.executeUpdate(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:453)
> at org.hibernate@5.3.15.Final//org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(HQLQueryPlan.java:378)
> at org.hibernate@5.3.15.Final//org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.executeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1550)
> at org.hibernate@5.3.15.Final//org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doExecuteUpdate(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1603)
> at org.hibernate@5.3.15.Final//org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.executeUpdate(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1585)
> ... 11 more Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection is
> closed.
> at com.microsoft//com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:234)
> at com.microsoft//com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.checkClosed(SQLServerConnection.java:1088)
> at com.microsoft//com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.prepareStatement(SQLServerConnection.java:3409)
> at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.20.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.doPrepareStatement(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:761)
> at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.20.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.prepareStatement(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:747)
> at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.20.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection$4.produce(WrappedConnection.java:478)
> at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.20.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection$4.produce(WrappedConnection.java:476)
> at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.20.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.SecurityActions.executeInTccl(SecurityActions.java:97)
> at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.20.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.prepareStatement(WrappedConnection.java:476)
> at org.hibernate@5.3.15.Final//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$1.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:90)
> at org.hibernate@5.3.15.Final//org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:176)
> ... 20 more

**EDITED:**

Here is the datasource configuration part within standalone-ha.xml

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:5.0">
        <datasources>
            <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS" pool-name="KeycloakDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" statistics-enabled="${wildfly.datasources.statistics-enabled:${wildfly.statistics-enabled:false}}">
                <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://sqlserver\sqlinstance:1431;DatabaseName=keycloak;</connection-url>
                <driver>sqlserver</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>keycloak</user-name>
                    <password>keycloak</password>
                </security>
            </datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                    <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
                <driver name="sqlserver" module="com.microsoft">
                    <driver-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver-class>
                    <xa-datasource-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
        </datasources>
    </subsystem>
```

Comment: Are you using the same connection object over and over, or are you getting a new connection from a connection pool and closing and disposing of it when finished?

Comment: As I know, keycloak uses connection pool and when any connection is not needed then it kills/disposes that connection.

Comment: You may know that but we can't see your screens and files. You haven't shown us any code or configuration. For all we know you've defined `<pool><max-pool-size>1</max-pool-size></pool> in your datasource configuration.

Comment: I have added the datasource configuration part from standalone-ha.xml. I have not defined any special configuration for pool-size. I use defaults from keycloak.